# Joi require unkown fields

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I am validating a GET request query string (using express-joi-validation) and require the user to pass at least one extra key value pair not directly specified in the schema.

I have tried to validate as follows:

```
const schema = Joi
    .object({
        requiredKey: Joi.string().required()
        knownExtraKey: Joi.boolean()
    })
    .pattern(/^/, Joi.string().required())

schema.validate({requiredKey: 'A'}) // valid but shouldn't be
schema.validate({requiredKey: 'A', name: "paul"}) // valid
```

Comment: Can you share your objects which you want to validate?

Comment: Literally any object should be valid. The issue I have is that it doesn't throw invalid when passed nothing. I've just edited the question to mention express-joi-validation, the library I am using to add joi validators to Express endpoints

Comment: Are you sure `.pattern()` is supposed to take two parameters like that?  If you search the documentation for "nested", you'll see that the property constraints are defined within an object passed to `keys({})`. I've never used Joi, so that's just my quick read for something else you could try.

Comment: If I modify my example to say `.pattern(/^/, Joi.string().valid('onlythis'))` and validate object `{a : 1}` I will get a validation error as expected so I believe my usage of .pattern is correct

Answer (score 1):

If you want at least one property:

`joi` version **17.2.1**

#### Explanation:

You need to specify the  minimum keys `object().min()` with the following formular: **number of required properties + 1**. In the example below the validation returns no error if you validate an object with 3 or 4 properties.

```js
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  one: Joi.string().required(),
  two: Joi.string().required(),
  three: Joi.string(),
  four: Joi.string(),
}).min(3);

// works
const data1 = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  three: 'three',
};
console.log(schema.validate(data1).error);

// works
const data2 = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  three: 'three',
  four: 'four',
};
console.log(schema.validate(data2).error);

// fails
const data3 = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
};
console.log(schema.validate(data3).error)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turns out I might have simplified my question too much! In my actual project there is a set of defined optional fields in the object schema too. So I guess what I'm wanting to validate is a minimum of 1 additional key

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this work for you? If yes, please also edit your question.

Comment: Question updated. I'm not sure if .min() is going to work as it's all about the number of unknown keys provided rather than the total number of keys.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. You have a predefined set of `required()` properties, you have some **known** optional properties and you have some **unknown** optional properties. Correct?

Comment: Correct, and at least one unknown property is required

Comment: Ok, got it. Last question: How many **known** optional properties do you have?

Comment: Let's say 3. I actually have multiple examples throughout my code with varying numbers.